# Enabling Basic Authentication For A Specific SharePoint Instance

Tags: authentication

My web host claims that he is unable to meet our company's request of enabling Basic Authentication for our hosted SharePoint site. While I understand that we can use NTLM, we are hoping for a slightly more secure solution. He says:

"Unfortunately, as we are on a hosted environment we cannot enable basic authentication as it will affect all sites residing on the same farm."

I am assuming that he is running some form of IIS. Is there a way that he can enable Basic Auth for a specific domain as opposed to opening all of them up to Basic Auth requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for more security, Basic Authentication is not something you should consider.When using Basic authentication,User name and password are transmitted between the client and server as clear text. So its not secure at all unless you use SSL.

In NTLM, the password is never transmitted across the wire and hence it is much more secure then Basic Authentication.

Now, coming to the sites issue. Authentication mechanism is set at web application level in IIS, So it will affect all site collections under that web application.